# Don't manage to get video displayed from win8.1 app store

Tags: iframe, windows-8.1, winjs

I am trying to display a youtube video from an iframe in my application welcome page, however It does not work and I am getting the error : 
APPHOST9613: The app couldn’t navigate to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Zlpzk2qspg because of this error: FORBIDFRAMING.

I try to display it using an  x-ms-webview then I get the message : 
This video is unavailable.

**The Adob Flash Player or an HTML5 supported browser is required
Get the latest flash player 
Learn more about upgrading to an html5 browser**

//However Adobe Flash player is already installed
the link 'Learn more about upgrading to an html5 browser' shows that the app integrated browser does NOT integrate formats  H.264/MSE &H.264/WebM VP8/MSE & WebM VP9
Do you have any idea how to get it fixed ?

Comment: Can you show us the iframe code?

Comment: Flash won't run in an `x-ms-webview`. It's only allowed to run in a restricted mode within IE. What do you want "fixed?" How are you trying to embed a video? There's no code in your question.

Comment: Here is the html code of my iframe : 
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Zlpzk2qspg" width="400" height="300" ></iframe>
there is no related code in js side
@WiredPrairie what I need is to get a youtube video displayed from my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ve managed to get it work with :

In HTML page >>

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Zlpzk2qspg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

In package.appxmanifest ContentURI >>

```
https://www.youtube.com/*/*
```